# Does the order of components going to ground count?

Tags: pcb, ground

Building a PCB, following the schematic there would be a specific order of the components going ground, but if I decide to let the signal go to ground in another point as shown in the schematic, would it affect the signal?

[image]

in the picture:

If I take R3 and plug it to ground after R21 instead of after R2, it still goes to ground, but the order is different.

Does it affect the signal? Does the output signal change?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "signal go to ground".

Comment: As shown in what schematic?

Comment: This question is pretty much impossible to answer without explaining what you mean with "components going to ground" and "order". The shortest way of explaining that would most certainly **editing your question, using the built-in schematic editor to add a schematic**. Thanks!

Comment: Milo, [you don't seem to have a grasp for how this site works](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/248089); you don't edit someone's post to comment on it. You can always comment on your own question. You should be reading the help pages!

Comment: Anyway, the edit you tried to make to an **answer** should probably have been an edit to you **question**; so, I'm doing that for you (one time!).

Comment: Sadly, your question still makes no sense: R3 and R21 have no "ordering". They both connect to ground. **What do you mean with *order***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. R3 and R21's ground points in what appears to be an audio pre-amplifier.*

> ... but if I decide to let the signal go to ground in another point as shown in the schematic, would it affect the signal?

- A schematic is not a physical wiring or layout diagram. It is supposed to show the *schema* or function and connections of the various componenents.
- All of the GND points are connected together and usually by extra-wide PCB tracks so that there is very low resistance between the components connected to GND.
- The PBC designer will use experience and design rules to minimise the likelihood of problems caused by poor layout. This generally means avoiding placing sensitive parts of the circuit close to high-powered parts where interference might result and placement of components such as decoupling capacitors C3 and C4 in their optimum position to do their intended job.

> If I take R3 and plug it to ground after R21 instead of after R2, it still goes to ground, but the order is different.

There is no order but you have probably increased the length of PCB trace into the circuit and this could cause problems such as interference pickup.

> Does it affect the signal? Does the output signal change?

If all goes well, no.

Comment: very helpful, thanks a lot !!

Comment: Good answer by transistor, as to the fact that a schematic is not a physical layout or physical representation of the circuit.  One additional point -  If you have a design where "order of connections" matter, that information is conveyed in a set of placement rules and routing rules that go to the layout house or the person who is going to be laying out and routing your printed wiring board.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what kind of circuits and return currents you have, but knowing how to ground is important and that is why concepts like star ground or ground plane exist. Obviously long wires with large currents are worse that short wires with large currents, and for example when building an audio amplifier, you dont't want the power amp ground path current cause any noise (fluctuation) on the preamp stage ground.

Comment: Please stop editing my post to continue discussion. If you have a comment, then add a comment.